# Java buttons repaint

Tags: java, swing

look at this simple code:

Main.java :

```
package CarManager;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static int width = 400;
    static int height = width / 16 * 9;
    static String title = "Car Manager";
    JButton viewTables = new JButton("View tables");
    JButton clients = new JButton("Clients");
    JButton search = new JButton("Search");
    JButton viewCars = new JButton("View all");
    JButton viewRent = new JButton("Rent a car");
    JButton viewBuy = new JButton("Buy a car");
    JButton viewAccessory = new JButton("Accessory");

    public Main() {

        setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(width, height);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("res\\background2.jpg"));
        add(background);
        background.setSize(width, height);
        add(viewTables);
        add(clients);
        add(search);
        viewTables.setBounds(20, 20, 110, 30);
        clients.setBounds(20, 70, 110, 30);
        search.setBounds(20, 120, 110, 30);

        viewTables.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                add(viewCars);
                viewCars.setBounds(260, 20, 110, 20);

                add(viewRent);
                viewRent.setBounds(260, 50, 110, 20);

                add(viewBuy);
                viewBuy.setBounds(260, 80, 110, 20);

                add(viewAccessory);
                viewAccessory.setBounds(260, 110, 110, 20);
            }
        });

        viewCars.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                View view = new View();
                view.addWindowListener(new WindowPlug(Main.this));
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

View.java:

```
package CarManager;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class View extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int width = 400;
    int height = width / 16 * 9;
    String title = "View all Cars";

    public View() {
        setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(width, height);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("res\\background2.jpg"));
        add(background);
        background.setSize(width, height);
    }
}
```

and WindowPlug.java:

```
package CarManager;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class WindowPlug extends WindowAdapter {

    private Main mainFrame;

    public WindowPlug(Main mainFrame) { // when creating an instance of this
                                        // WindowAdapter, tell it with which
                                        // Main Window you are working with
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.revalidate();
    }
}
```

when i click view tables and then view all (those are the buttons that work for now)
and the first window hides and a new window appears, now when i close the second window the first one appears visible but the buttons are not visible, i have to hover over with the mouse for them to be visible again. ive tried `mainFrame.revalidate();` and

```
mainFrame.repaint();
```

but no result
im using windows 8.1 pro

Comment: Please see edit to answer. Please indicate that you've read my answer. I have more I can add, but no sense expending the effort if it's for naught.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your code, and I'm not sure if this is the main problem since your code works fine on my system, is that you're calling `setVisible(true)` on your main window *before* you've added all your components. It should only be called *after* all components have been added.

Other problems unrelated to your main question:

- You should avoid using null layout. While using null layout may seem to a newbie the better way to create complex GUI's, it's a fallacy, and more you create Swing GUI's the more you learn to respect and use the layout managers and see that these creatures help immensely in creating flexible, beautiful and if need be, complex GUI's. Then you can let them size them selves appropriately by calling `pack()` prior to setting them visible.
- It appears that you really want to use a CardLayout to swap *views* on one GUI rather than spitting multiple GUI's at the user.
- If you absolutely must display a dialog window, then you should use a JDialog, not a JFrame. If you used a modal JDialog, you wouldn't be needing a WindowListener.

---

**Edit**

- OK, a big problem I see is that you're using null layout and adding a JLabel that covers the whole contentPane, and then adding components to the same contentPane.
- Instead, make the JLabel your contentPane, and then add your JButtons, etc to ***it***.
- But make sure that the JLabel's opaque property is set to true first.

---

**Edit 2**
If you need to use an image as a background image you can:

- Put the Image in an ImageIcon, put the Icon in a JLabel, and again use the JLabel as your contentPane. Again, you will need to make the JLabel opaque by calling `setOpaque(true)` on it. This works well if you don't want to change the size of the image or the window.
- If you do need to change the size of the image, better to have a JPanel draw the image in its `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, and then use this JPanel as your contentPane.
- Once you've created your contentPane, then set its layout and add your components to it.
- Then call `setContentPane(newContentPane)` on your top level window and pass in the new contentPane.

Comment: woooooow , nononono, thanks for all the other tips on how to form a program , but now i see whats wrong :D
first the buttons are drawn then the background :D
and that is why it works on everyone else but mine :D
no one has the background but me :D
ill take in mind how to layout the program using your tips but for now how do i set a z index if there is such a thing ?

Comment: @user3316177: see **Edit 2**.